# Licensing for Open Source Geographic Information System?

Tags: open-source-gis, license

I would like to ask about the licence.

This software is presented as "Open Source Geographic Information System" but it is free also for company?

Can I use it for creation of commercial maps in my business?

It seems to be good alternative to ArcWIE.

Comment: It would help if you identified *WHAT SPECIFIC* software you were interested in?  There are many open-source GIS software products.

Comment: I guess QGIS - its the first google hit (for me) for that exact phrase.

Comment: What is ArcWIE?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use Open Source GIS software commercially (within the context of the respective license). See also:

- [Free Software and Open Source Business Models](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/drupal6/sites/www.e-education.psu.edu.geog583/files/OpenSourceBusinessModels.pdf) (by A. Christl)
- [Business models for open-source software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_models_for_open-source_software) (Wikipedia)
- [Don't oppose Free Software and Commercial Software](http://gis.cri.fmach.it/don-t-oppose-free-software-and-commercial-software/) (by J. Wagner)